# Presto and Hive

Tags: amazon-s3, presto

I'm trying to enable basic SQL querying of CSV files located in an s3 directory.  Presto seemed like a natural fit (the files are 10s GB).  As I went through the setup in Presto, I tried creating a table using the Hive connector.  It was not clear to me if I only needed the hive metastore to save my table configurations in Presto, or if I have to create them in there first.

The documentation makes it seem that you can use Presto without having to CONFIGURE Hive, but using Hive syntax.  Is that accurate?  My experiences are that AWS S3 has not been able to connect.

Comment: Side-note: You could also consider using [Amazon Athena](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/what-is.html), which is a serverless implementation of Presto. However, it is only in a few regions at the moment.

Comment: I would love to use Amazon Athena, but it's not compliant for my particular use case (healthcare)

Comment: _My experiences are that AWS S3 has not been able to connect._ -- What was the problem, exactly? Presto Hive connector supports S3 (at least `s3a://`) out of the box, if you use IAM Roles to grant EC2 machines access to S3.

Answer (score 1):

Presto syntax is similar to Hive syntax. For most simple queries, the identical syntax would function in both. However, there are some key differences that make Presto and Hive not entirely the same thing. For example, in Hive, you might use `LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE`, whereas in Presto you'd use `CROSS JOIN UNNEST`. There are many such examples of nuanced syntactical differences between the two.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use vanilla Presto to analyze data on S3 without Hive. Presto provides only distributed execution engine. However, it lacks metadata information about tables. Thus, Presto Coordinator needs Hive to retrieve table metadata to parse and execute a query.

However, you can use AWS Athena, which is managed Presto, to run queries on top of S3.

Another option, in recent [0.198 release](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/release/release-0.198.html) Presto adds a capability to connect AWS Glue and retrieve table metadata on top of files in S3.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but if this question is still outstanding, have you considered using Spark? Spark connects easily with out-of-the-box methods and can query/process data living in S3/CSV formats.

Also, I'm curious: what solution did you end up implementing to resolve your issue?